# TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null, multer nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, multer

I'm getting this error while submitting the form: TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null, my form action is: /sliders, this is my code:

```
router.post("/sliders", upload.single("image"), function (req, res, next) {
  const filename = req.file.filename;
  let slider = new Slider({
    title: req.body.title,
    desc: req.body.desc,
    image: req.file.filename,
  });
  post.save();

  res.redirect("/sliders");
});
```

This is my form, I have the exact same form and I'm creating post with it with no problems ofc the only diffrence is the action:

```
 <form
            method="POST"
            action="/sliders"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
            novalidate
          >
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                <label>Slider Title</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="title"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Title"
                  id="title"
                  required
                />
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                <label>Subject</label>
                <textarea
                  rows="5"
                  class="form-control"
                  name="desc"
                  placeholder="Subject"
                  id="subject"
                  required
                ></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="from-group">
                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="image"
                  class="form-control-file rounded-0"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <br />
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              id="sendMessageButton"
            >
              Post
            </button>
          </form>
```

Comment: Please show how you send form data and what data you send

Comment: I've edit the post take a look and thank you

Comment: Can you also show a body of a request?

Comment: I think I found the problem but I'm don't know why it's happening, I have a post route and a slider route both have multer, the post route is posting the data to the DB and the file is uploaded but when I try the same with slider it's giving image of null some how it's taking the image name from the post form and trying to assign it to the slider form